# How can I reserve registers in LLVM?

Tags: compiler-construction, arm, llvm, code-generation, llvm-ir

I am trying to implement a special compiler level LLVM pass, which will have to reserve 20 registers amongst the available 32 GPRs in ARM micro-architecture, so that I will be performing my experiments on these reserved registers. I am intending to do this at IR level. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking to edit the RegisterInfo.td file. I haven't done specifically what you're trying to do but look at Target.td for some hints. IsAllocatable looks promising or possibly deleting the registers you don't want LLVM to use.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely won't be at the IR level as IR registers are virtual and infinite. You can mark registers as reserved with *XXXRegisterInfo::getReservedRegs()*.

```
BitVector XXXRegisterInfo::getReservedRegs(const MachineFunction &MF) const {
  BitVector Reserved(getNumRegs());

  Reserved.set(XXX::REGX);

  return Reserved;
}
```